# How to calculate the exponential of all elements in an input array using qiskit?

Tags: qiskit, programming, quantum-algorithms, mathematics, measurement

How can I perform an operation similar to `Numpy.exp()` in qiskit?

Comment: Your requirement is confusing. For others to better answer your question, more detail, please.

Comment: I am doing a program based on image processing.So I want to calculate the gradients in the aspect of quantum computing.

Comment: `gx = cv2.Sobel(log_image, cv2.CV_64F, 1, 0, ksize=3)`
`gy = cv2.Sobel(log_image, cv2.CV_64F, 1, 0, ksize=3)`
`ex = np.exp(-1 * abs(gx))`
`ey = np.exp(-1 * abs(gy))`

Comment: I want to do those np.exp operations in the aspects of quantum computing..how can I do that?

Comment: You want to do it with the quantum state? Denoted the operation by $\hat U$, is $\hat U|x\rangle=e^{ix}|x\rangle$ what you want?

Comment: I want to do the exponential and multiplication operation in this code in quantum computing aspects.It is the code of an image filter based on the paper 'spatial stimuli gradient sketch model'.

Comment: `def SSGSM(img):`

   `log_image = np.log(1 + np.float32(img))`
   `gx = cv2.Sobel(log_image, cv2.CV_64F, 1, 0, ksize=3)`
   `gy = cv2.Sobel(log_image, cv2.CV_64F, 1, 0, ksize=3)`
   `ex = np.exp(-1 * abs(gx))`
   `ey = np.exp(-1 * abs(gy))`
   `vx = np.multiply(gx, ex)`
   `vy = np.multiply(gy, ey)`
   `vx = np.multiply(vx, vx)`
   `vy = np.multiply(vy, vy)`
   `v_ = vx + vy`
   `v = np.sqrt(v_)`
   `return v`

Comment: Can I contact you through email?

Comment: Yes, mailto:wangyitian19@mails.ucas.edu.cn. I'm not sure whether we are thinking about the same thing, but I think your requirement is possible but requires huge resources. Maybe you can see the paper:https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/0205095.

Answer (score 3):

Just import numpy and use it as usual. For example:

```
import numpy as np
array = [1, 2 , 3]
exp_array = np.exp(array)
print('expoential of array:', exp_array)
```

The output is:

```
expoential of array: [ 2.71828183  7.3890561  20.08553692]
```